# Trigger signal in akka streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream

This code snippet in [akka-stream cookbook documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#Triggering_the_flow_of_elements_programmatically) illustrates how to trigger the flow of elements programmatically :

```
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val zip = builder.add(Zip[Message, Trigger]())
  elements ~> zip.in0
  triggerSource ~> zip.in1
  zip.out ~> Flow[(Message, Trigger)].map { case (msg, trigger) => msg } ~> sink
  ClosedShape
})
```

In this example, how `Trigger` and `triggerSource` would look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`Trigger` can be anything, as you can see from the graph logic, it's getting discarded all the time. Most likely it will be

```
case object Trigger
```

2.`triggerSource` is any valid `Source[Trigger, _]`. See the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#Source_stages) for a list of possibilities.

Note that this specific example involves a `ClosedShape` materializing to `NotUsed`, so it will need tweaking if you need to access `triggerSource` materialized value, or connecting this to a more complex graph producing `Trigger`s.